# Is there any notation for a set of real valued bounded functions and the notation also include the information of bounds?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, scientific-notation

For, e.g., Let $|{f(x)}|\le m$ and $x\in \mathbb{X}$. I want to define $f(x)$ as a $f(x) \in \mathcal{B}_{m}(\mathbb{X})$. Is there any such notation?

Comment: I can't recall any standard notation, but you can easily define such an object as you have, or more rigorously in set notation. The notation itself is not particularly important so long as the reader understands its meaning.

Comment: Since your constraint is $f(x)\in[-m,\,m]$, [the set of such functions is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Set_exponentiation) $[-m,\,m]^{\Bbb X}$.